# Could not authenticate to SharePoint Online using OAuth 2.0

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I am using following commands to connect to my SharePoint Online environment.

1. Connect-SPOService -Url "https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test1"
2. Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test1"

In an ideal case this command should connect me to the site collection. I have verified that I am using correct UserName and Password.

But instead I am getting following errors

**For command 1**:

> Connect-SPOService : Could not authenticate to SharePoint Online
>   https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test1 using OAuth 2.0 At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Connect-SPOService -Url "https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test1"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], AuthenticationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.AuthenticationException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.ConnectSPOService

**For command 2**:

> Connect-PnPOnline : The remote server returned an error: (403)
>   Forbidden. At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test1 ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline

**Unusual behavior**: When I am running below command.

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://testdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/test1 
-PnPO365ManagementShell -LaunchBrowser
```

i.e. with parameters "*PnPO365ManagementShell*" "*LaunchBrowser*", it works perfectly fine. I am not sure what's wrong.

**Similar behavior**
Also I have installed the nuget package for `SharePointPnPCoreOnline v3.1.1809` in my Provisioning solution. So when I am running my provisioning code I get same error while establishing connection.

**Last thing**: When I use same commands from other VMs or colleagues machine with same Creds, it works perfectly fine. Means something is wrong on my machine.

Comment: did it use to work earlier and after a couple of days stopped working ? or it was always broken ?

Comment: Yes it used to work earlier on my projects and machine. Then I was on On-Prem project for 7 months. Since Oct2018 its the problem..Now I got chance to post it on SP.SE

Comment: @GautamSheth there were many failed windows upgrades on my local system. Could these be a problem? Although I got that all clean now, but still same issue.

Comment: can you try `Remove-PnPStoredCredential -Name https://tenant.sharepoint.com -Force` and then try to connect again ? Looks like those creds got stored , this command might help

Comment: @GautamSheth it says credential not found.

Comment: not sure, for command 1, would suggest that you connect to the admin site, i.e `Connect-SPOService -Url "https://testdomain-admin.sharepoint.com/` because SPO commandlets only work with admin site urls

Comment: @GautamSheth No worries buddy :) Many thanks for your help so far.. Greatly appreciate that.

Comment: I'm not sure but you must use you're SharePoint tenant management url. Check D Sam's answer.

Comment: for Connect-SPOService - it connects to admin site only

Comment: check PnP module versions;
try -Interactive switch

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to connect myself to SPO (but also MSO,AZureAD, ...) :

```
$username = "test@exemple.com"
$password = "password"

$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)

Connect-SPOService -Url https://testdomain-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred 
#as said in the comments, you need to connect to the admin url of SPO
```